# Differential equation: $9xy''+9y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Since we have variable coefficients we will use the cauchy-euler method to solve this DE. First we substitute $y=x^m$ into our given DE. This then gives
"

$9x(m(m-1)x^{m-2}) + 9mx^{m-1} = 0$

Note that:

$x^{m-2} = x^{m-1}x^{-1}$

Then

$9x(m(m-1)x^{m-1}x^{-1}) + 9mx^{m-1} = 0$

$9(m(m-1)x^{m-1}) + 9mx^{m-1} = 0$

$9mx^{m-1}((m-1)) + 9mx^{m-1} = 0 \Rightarrow m-1=0$

$m_{1} = 1$ so $y_{1}=c_{1}x$ is our solution and using reduction of order we get our second solution which is $y_{2}=c_{2}x\ln(x)$ and by superposition of homogenous equations we get our general solution

$y = c_{1}x + c_{2}x\ln(x)$

However i am told that this is wrong and the answer is $y=c_{1} + c_{2}\ln(x)$

What happened to the factor x?

Comment: You have $9mx^{m-1}((m-1)) + 9mx^{m-1} = 0$ but not $m-1=0$.  Start back at this point.

Comment: right so its $m-1+1=0$ thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have that $m^2=0 \implies m=0$ is a double root you have to multiply by $\ln |x|$ in order to find the second solution:
$$y_1=x^0=1$$
$$\implies y_2= 1 \times \ln |x|$$
$$y(x)=y_1+y_2 =C_1+C_2 \ln |x|$$

Comment: What happens if $x<0$?

Comment: it's aboslute value of $x$ @MichaelRozenberg

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(xy')'=0$$ or
$$xy'=C$$ or
$$y=C\ln|x|+C_1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

you can multiply by $x$ to make it Euler Cauchy Differential Equation ,see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation